# How to resurrect the iPhone 12?

Tags: iphone

I have iPhone 12 64Gb, I got a notification that the memory was almost full, then I tried to delete a few apps from the phone, but it was weird because they still were on the screen like I tried to delete them, but nothing happen... Then I decided to reboot the phone (turn it off and on) and now I see such a screen (screenshot attached)

[image]

and sometimes (like once in 3 min) I see that it opens a desktop for a sec and comes back to the loading state...

What could be a possible reason for such behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you see when you plug it into a computer?

And have you tried hard restart: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412

Comment: @MyPreciousss oh, thanks! It works for me, I just make a hard reset and it is ok:) Actually, I tried it, but in the wrong way, I tried to click and hold all the buttons, but in my case (following your link) I needed to try a specific combination. Would you like to post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a hard reset for the spinner issue.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412